# Time Dilation (slowing) based on 0 to 1, and the amount it influences

Tags: c#, math, time, percentage, stopwatch

Hopefully I can explain this. So I'm making a game, and I want to control the passage of time for the different objects in the world. I want a global dilation that I can pause the game (all objects and their timers) with. I want a dilation that is room specific that some objects are affected by, but others may not be. I also want ones specific to the individual entities themselves. This was what I was thinking:

```
List<Tuple<double,double>> DilationAffectors = stuff;
```

This list would be all the Dilations affecting the object, and the impact that they have over the object (0 being no effect, .5 means halfway affected, 1 is full effect). The following logic is kinda how I would apply it to the passage of time

```
var elapsedTime = 0.0;
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.start();
While(true)
{                     //The function in question
    double dilation = getDilation(DilationAffectors);        

    var timeBetween = stopwatch.Elapsed - LastTick;
    elapsedTime += TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)(timeBetween.Ticks * dilation));
    LastTick = stopwatch.Elapsed;
    //...
}
```

So I've tried a number of variations on the getDilation function, but I can't seem to get the math right.

- If the room is a speed of 1.0 it shouldn't affect the object's speed
- If the Global is a speed of 0, time should not pass at all
- If the object specific dilation is .5, it should move at half speed. (unless affected by room speed, then it's half of the room speed)
- etc. etc. for other conditions

I can't seem to get the different dilations to play together.
If one has a dilation of 0, but affects the object by 0, it still affects it in certain ways. I tried averaging them, but this wasn't the desired effect.
I can't seem to find the solution to this math equation. Am I over-complicating this? Or thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Just multiply all the dilation factors together.

Comment: That doesn't work. If I have a Dilation of 0, and it influences the object by 0, then it stops the entity despite having no influence. Your suggestion would work without those influence values, and that might be my last resort

Comment: Your question did not mention anything about influence (other than in the title). If you mean by influence what I think, then raise the dilation factors to the power of the respective influence. Then, anything with influence 0 will produce a factor of 1, which has no effect on dilation.

Comment: Sorry, I tried simplifying the explanation, and I guess I left out too much. Thanks good sir! That is exactly what I needed! way more straightforward than I was thinking haha.